# How to get path to read file from root dir C?

Tags: c

I have 2 files in the root of my project

```
ps.as

ps_error.as
```

there is a screenshot

[image]

And there is how I can try to open this file

```
fp = fopen(strcat(filename, AS_FILE_EXT), "r");  // filename (ps / ps_error), AS_FILE_EXT (.as)

        /*if no file - error message and not compile*/
        if (!fp) {
            fprintf(stderr, "File \"%s\" not found!", filename);
            continue;
        }
```

And output is

> File "ps.as" not found!File "ps_error.as" not found!

As far as I know in order to read the file from the root of the project I need to pass just a file name, so why it does not work?

Comment: You can pass the file name only if you're _executing_ your program from the same directory. Have you tried running your program from `mmn14`?

Comment: @ForceBru Yes, it works, tnx! I am working from `CLion` and if I try to debug directly from IDE, so I get this error, but if in debug configuration I set path to working dir, it works. Also, I did not notice that if I try to execute my program from console it works

Comment: Does `filename` has enough memory available to hold the extension? `As far as I know in order to read the file from the root of the project I need to pass just a file name` That depends on the current working directory your program is executed from.